# The Open With: application settings In Finder's Get Info sheet for a file type won't stay set

Tags: macos, finder, text-editor

When I set "Open with:" from Finder's Get Info sheet for a file and click "Change All...", it will open in the designated app if I immediately open the file, but the application set for "Open with:" doesn't stay for long.

For instance, for some reason the OS "decideds" that .txt files are to be opened with Numbers. I reset it to BBEdit over and over but Numbers keeps opening these files. The same file set to BBEdit will open with Numbers the next day. Same problem with other file extensions insisting on using e.g. Xcode to open them.

To be clear, if I reset the file with "Open with:" from Finder's Get Info sheet and click "Change All...", it will open with the preferred application I just set right afterwards, but will revert to e.g. Numbers or Xcode etc after a short time.

How can I make the changes stick?

And why is this happening?

Comment: The question is, hmm, missing an actual question :-)

Comment: Okay the questions would be: 1) why is this happening, and 2) how do I fix it. Sorry I'm a newb and thought that would be apparent as this is broken according to what I understand about the OS.